# animating NSString drawn using drawAtRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a couple of `UILabel's` and I decided that I wanted to improve the performance a bit by just drawing the `NSString` directly using `NSString drawAtRect` instead of using labels. This all worked fine, except that later on I have a button in this view that would animate what is before a `UILabel`. How can I now animate the `NSString` that is drawn using `drawRect`?

The animation is pretty simple, it's something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kDefaultAnimationDuration*2 animations:^{
        self.storyTitleLabel.alpha = 0.0;
        self.publisherNameLabel.alpha = 0.0;
        self.highlightButton.alpha = 0.0;
        self.highlightButton.enabled = NO;

        self.userFullName_.alpha = 1.0;
        self.lineDivider_.alpha = 1.0;
        self.numberOfHighlights_.alpha = 1.0;

        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.userFullName_];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.numberOfHighlights_];

        [self.userProfileButton setFrame:CGRectMake(115, 30, kProfilePicSize, kProfilePicSize)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

it's essentially fading in a bunch of `UILabel's`

Comment: Does this actually improve performance over using a UILabel? Have you actually tested that performance?

Comment: I was thinking that drawRect must be much faster than UIlabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean `drawInRect; withFont:`. That draws on a `UIView`. You can animate the alpha of that `UIView` in the same way you propose above. If you draw lots of different things on the `UIView`, and don't want the animation to apply to all of them, you are stuck. You would have to create another `UIView` of the right size, add it as a subview to the first `UIView`, and draw in that . Much like a `UILabel`, in fact...

Comment: but I can't do a set alpha on a UISString and how do I get a reference to the string that I've drawn?

Comment: You have to animate the alpha of the UIView, I think.